# How do I execute the following query?

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql. I have a table called orders with the fields `orderid`, `orderdate`, `customerid`, `shippedcity` and `amount`.

I want to show orders for the month of June and year 2011. Please help.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried before asking for help.

Comment: I would also like to advice to take up a basic course of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BETWEEN` as below:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM ORDER 
   WHERE ODERDATE BETWEEN DATE ('01-06-2011') AND DATE ('30-06-2011');
```

Answer (score 1):

this one is fairly easy :-)

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE MONTH(orderdate) = 6
   AND YEAR(orderdate) = 2011
```

For better performance of the query you could use this one

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders
 WHERE orderdate BETWEEN '2011-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-06-30 23:59:59'
```

Cheers -Sven

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE MONTH(orderdate) = 6 AND
       YEAR(orderDate) = 2011
```

for reference,

**[MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)** 
**[YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)**

Answer (score -1):

well, first of all i have to ask, does the orderdate field contains full date (dd/mm/yyyy)? or how is the date stored?
you could try `SELECT orderid FROM orders WHETE orderdate = 'your date in the correct format it is stored'`

Comment: -1 as this is more of a comment than an answer, and the partial solution offered is incorrect (he wants them for a whole month, not a single date)